# How to concatenate two columns into a new one in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, datagrip

I have a problem while merging two columns into a new one. I just want to concatenate the columns IBAN and Currency_code into CheckSum. And when I make a `SELECT *` it appears.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS transaccio;
CREATE TABLE transaccio (
   IBAN varchar(255),
   Currency_code varchar (255),
   CheckSum varchar(255)
);
```

I have raised two options, but none of them works.

Option one:

```
INSERT INTO transaccio(CheckSum) SELECT (CONCAT(IBAN, Currency_code)) FROM transaccio;
```

Option two: (it says that don't know from where get the IBAN and Currency_code)

```
INSERT INTO transaccio(CheckSum) VALUES (CONCAT(IBAN, Currency_code));
```

Comment: Which database MySQL or PostgreSQL? But both should support CONCAT function.

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO transaccio(CheckSum, IBAN, Currency_code) VALUES (CONCAT(IBAN, Currency_code), 'IBAN', 'Currency_code');`.. But from the question it is hard to understand if you are looking for a insert of update query..

Comment: Besides iam wondering if you really want to generate that easy of a geuss check sum for money systems.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new haha, done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`Update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) query instead of `Insert`:

```
UPDATE transaccio 
SET CheckSum = CONCAT(IBAN, Currency_code);
```

However it seems to be a [Generated Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) problem. Depending on your **MySQL** version, you could use Generated Columns instead.

**PostgreSQL** does not support Generated Columns / Virtual Columns natively **yet**. You may refer this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/183265/27070 to emulate them in PostgreSQL

Comment: To make this anwer better PostgreSQL does not support generated columns/virtual columns natively This is https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/183265/27070 how you simulate generated columns/virtual columns in PostgreSQL..

Comment: @RaymondNijland please feel free to edit the answer and add this very interesting info

Comment: @PedroGarcía-Mauriño happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE transaccio
SET CheckSum = CONCAT(IBAN, Currency_code);
```